# Toolbar not collapsing with TabLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, androiddesignsupport, android-tablayout

I would like to let the `Toolbar` collapse when the user scrolls in one of the `TabLayout`'s tabs (supplied by `ViewPager`).

This is the functionality I desire:

[image]

[image]

**However, my layout does not only not scroll, but also *cuts off* content at the bottom** (to be exact, it cuts off 48dp - the height of a toolbar):

[image]

I use the ViewPager to display each Fragment as a tab. The Fragments consist of a simple `ScrollView` holding a `TextView`. Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/ueber_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/ueber_tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/ueber_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Each fragment has the following layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ueber_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:linksClickable="false"
        android:textColorLink="#000000"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:padding="16dp"/>

</ScrollView>
```

The ViewPager is set up by a ViewPagerAdapter:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.ueber_viewpager);

ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFrag(new ContentFragment(), "Über");
adapter.addFrag(new ContentFragment(), "Impressum");
adapter.addFrag(new ContentFragment(), "Lizenzen");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.ueber_tabLayout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: Just use the code from here:https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/tree/master/app/src/main

Comment: This blog post might help http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `NestedScrollView` instead of a `ScrollView`.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: This did it! On a slightly unrelated note though, I have set android:windowTranslucentStatus=true in my app theme, and now the toolbar is visible trough the status bar when scrolling down. I need that setting though to make the navigation drawer visible behind the status bar. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score -2):

When the user scrolls in to the fragment, hide the toolbar:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

When they scroll back to the top, show the toolbar:

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Comment: No, he is using the new design library.